# Adding third party library to Salesforce LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-dom

I'm trying to create an address search component using Dawa Address library (Danish Addresses) https://dawadocs.dataforsyningen.dk/dok/guide/autocomplete#trin-2-installer-dawa-autocomplete2-komponenten

This is my js code

```javascript
import corejs from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/corejs";
import dawaFetch from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/dawaFetch";
import dawaAutocomplete from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/dawaAutocomplete";
import dawaStyles from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/dawaStyles";

import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";

export default class DawaAddress extends LightningElement {
  hasRendered = false;
  isLoading = false;

  renderedCallback() {
    if (this.hasRendered) {
      return;
    }
    this.hasRendered = true;
    this.isLoading = true;
    
    Promise.all([
      loadScript(this, dawaAutocomplete + '/dawa.js'),
      loadScript(this, corejs + '/core.js'),
      loadScript(this, dawaFetch + '/fetch.js'),
      loadStyle(this, dawaStyles)
    ])
      .then(() => {
        this.initAddress();
        this.isLoading = false;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error = ", err);
        console.log(err);
      });

  }

  initAddress() {
    const addressElm = this.template.querySelector("input");
    console.log("addresselm = ", addressElm);
    if (addressElm) {
      dawaAutocomplete.dawaAutocomplete(addressElm, {
        select: function (selected) {
          console.log("Valgt adresse: " + selected.tekst);
        }
      });
      addressElm.blur();
      // eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-async-operation
      setTimeout(() => {
        addressElm.focus();
      }, 100);
    } else {
      console.error("No input element found");
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my template code

```html
<template>
    <div class="autocomplete-container">
      <div class='autocomplete-container'>
        <input type="text" id="adresse">
      </div>
        <!-- Suggestions will appear here -->
    </div>
</template>
```

When I type in the front end, it throws this error

> Uncaught TypeError: d.default.dawaAutocomplete is not a function throws at

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use this on lightning-input at all, because the dawa library needs to manipulate an `HTMLInputElement`, which is protected by the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom) in LWC. If you want SLDS styling but still have this work, you'll have to adapt the [Input](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/) blueprint and then load the script, having it attach to the native input instead. I'm not sure what it's supposed to look like when it's done, but I did manage a simple example, which I'll link below.

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/IzFfWWHXPEcJ1V6QgTRc/src/app.js?p=stories).

Comment: I was thinking that because it's an npm library, the default export did not work as expected ... looked into into perhaps changing to an ES6 module, but looked like too much work. Am I wrong in thinking that might have been the issue?

Comment: @CasparHarmer It's not a default export. The actual code I needed was `import { dawaAutocomplete } from "dawa-autocomplete2"` (in my npm-based example). I think the entire thing ends up being a function if you import it as a static resource, so it'd probably be `dawaAutocomplete(...)` instead of `dawaAutocomplete.dawaAutocomplete(...)`.

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you for the demo and I tried to implement in the project and it doesn't get loaded I guess because I'm still getting the. error 

`dawaAddress.js:1 Error =  TypeError: r.default is not a function
    at p.handleAddress (dawaAddress.js:1:2047)
    at eval (dawaAddress.js:1:1963)`

I edit the code in the question to the new implementation

Comment: @sfdcfox It looks like I may need to add core js and fetch js but it looks like core js has some issues, that the loadScript throws undefined error